# How can I debug in Eclipse Step by Step?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new to Android Development, I'm using Eclipse Juno, 
My doubt is, can I debug my errors step by step?
I mean as I use F10 in asp.Net development, something like that? so that I can know values of different variables at any point of the program running.

Comment: To start the application use the little green bug instead of the green arrow.

Comment: set breakpoints and run the app in debug mode

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the 'Run' menu item in Eclipse? The second item is 'Debug'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a breakpoint where you want to start debugging by right clicking on the side bar next to the line and selecting "Toggle breakpoint". Then press "F11" and you're done.